# php mysql_connect(): Connection using old (pre-4.1.1) authentication protocol refused

Tags: php, mysql

so i'm using ispconfig 3.0.5.4p8 to host some online game website
and the online game server is using mysql 4.0
the database is on a remote machine
the website i'm using right now is connecting to the database with mysql_connect
when i'm opening the website it says

```
Warning: mysql_connect(): Connection using old (pre-4.1.1) authentication protocol refused (client option 'secure_auth' enabled) in /var/www/clients/client0/web4/web/class/shop_func.php on line 11 Can't connect to db
```

i can't change the mysql database because the game server doesn't support newer mysql server

the search result on google is nothing pointing to my problem..
most of them is just saying because the mysql client is too old..infact what i think i'm dealing right now is the mysql is too old..

the ispconfig php version is 5.3.29
the mysql version is 4.0 portable

Comment: Dear  god....  Change the database server. But that is just one of the few problems.

Comment: @itachi i can't..i want to but i just can't..the game server is very old and can't support newer mysql..